# Configure 2d php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to adjust a php chart library on my code with some data fetched from a database. I am too close but i think i am confused with all these arrays. I will try to explain as easy as possible. The appropriate form of constructing the data that my library needs to read in order to create a php chart is the following:

```
//With this value my api displays the chart normally
$p->data = array(array(array("2015/10/10",44),array("2015/10/11",56)));
```

The way i'm trying to construct the aforementioned array is the following

```
//Fetch results from database and push values into an array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $values[] = array($row['Date'] => $row['Total']);
}
$p->data = array(array($values));
```

But unfortunately the chart is not displaying my values. How can i fix my code in order to achive this format:

```
$p->data = array(array(array("2015/10/10",44),array("2015/10/11",56)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting `$row['Date']` as the key and `$row['Total']` as the value, which, if you run `print_r($p->data)` results in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [2015/10/10] => 44
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [2015/10/11] => 56
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

You actually need

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $values[] = array($row['Date'], $row['Total']);
}
```

This way, you will get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2015/10/10
                            [1] => 44
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2015/10/11
                            [1] => 56
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

If the array should be the same as the first code example, you don't need the `=>`. So, you can just do the following:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $values[] = array($row['Date'], $row['Total']);
}
```

The `=>` creates a key value pair with the first item as the key and the second as the value. If you use a `,`, it creates a flat array with those items as values.

Comment: Thank you very much all!

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping one too many arrays:

```
$p->data = array(array(array("2015/10/10",44),array("2015/10/11",56)));
            ^-A   ^-B   ^-C0                    ^-C1
```

and then

```
  $values[] = array($row['Date'] => $row['Total']);
               ^-C0,C1,C2,etc...
      ^--B
}
$p->data = array(array($values));
                   ^--A
              ^---????
```